# Can I create a second pull request for the same branch to be merged into a different branch?

Tags: github

on my local repository, I created a feature branch A from branch B.
I did some work on branch A, and pushed it to github, and created a pull request to ask for merging branch A into branch B.

While the pull request is still open, I am asked to create a second pull request to ask for merging branch A into branch C. I can't find out where I can create the second pull request. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get to the compare page for branches A and C. The URL looks something like this:

https://github.com/user/repository/compare/C...A

If there's no pull request to merge A into C, then you'll see a Create pull request button.

To get there without writing the URL manually, go to the branches page in your repository and open the one you want to use to open the pull request (A). Then, click on Compare, which will open the compare page for the default branch (master) and the given branch. Finally, change the base branch if it's a branch other than the default one.

Comment: Thanks. Your reply is on the github. Someone told me on my local repository, use `git stash` to do something, but I didn't understand what he told me. Could you guess what he suggested me to do?

Comment: You can take a look at the Git book for more information about stashing: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning. Or the documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash. If you're working on a branch, the branch is in a messy state, and you want to switch branches to work on something else, you can stash your work and switch, and then go back and recover everything.

Does that help?